# Как сделать функцию меньше 25 строк

Tags: c, алгоритм

Мне нужно придумать функцию `ft_print_comb` в 25 строк кода(или меньше), которая выведет результат таким образом: 
`012, 013, 014, 015, 016, 017, 018, 019, 023, ..., 789`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е. каждая правая цифра больше левых цифр

Правила написания кода: 
1. Можно использовать только библиотеку `unistd.h`
2. Нельзя объявлять сразу несколько переменых, типа: `int i, j, k`, только одну
3. После объявления переменных нужно делать одну пустую строку
4. Создавать ещё функции нельзя
5. Нельзя использовать любой цикл, кроме `while`
6. Функции и циклы в `ft_print_comb` нужно писать таким образом, это входит в длину функции:

```
void    ft_print_comb(void)
{
  //code
}

while 
{
  //code
}
```

У меня получилось сделать `ft_print_comb` только в 26 строк кода, возможно, вы знаете, как можно это решить намного короче?

```
#include <unistd.h>

void    ft_putchar(char letter)
{
    char c;

    c = (char)letter;
    write(1, &c, 1);
}

void    ft_print_comb(void)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;

    i = 0;
    while (i < 10)
    {
        j = i + 1;
        while (j < 10)
        {
            k = j + 1;
            while (k < 10)
            {
                ft_putchar(i + 48);
                ft_putchar(j + 48);
                ft_putchar(k + 48);
                write(1, " ", 1);
                k++;
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}

int     main() 
{
    ft_print_comb();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: весьма странный набор правил... например можно просто включить инкремент в условие...

Comment: @Fat-Zer это я обучаюсь, моя учебная среда мне так диктует и просит делать функцию меньше 25 строк

Comment: Так дополнительные функции можно создавать или нет? 4 и 6 пункты и 2 функции в вашем решении немного сбивают с толку.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker новую функцию нельзя создавать, поправил пункты

Comment: @МихаилКамахин функция `ft_putchar` дана по условию?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker да

Comment: Код "char c;
c = (char)letter;"
Можно заменить на "char c = (char) letter;"
Аналогично и с "int i; ... i = 0" можно заменить на "int i = 0;"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно конечно еще сократить, но для соблюдения условий этого должно быть достаточно.

```c
void ft_print_comb(void)
{
    int n = 0;

    while (n < 1000)
    {
        char a = n / 100 % 10;
        char b = n / 10 % 10;
        char c = n % 10;

        if (a < b && b < c)
        {
            ft_putchar('0' + a);
            ft_putchar('0' + b);
            ft_putchar('0' + c);
            ft_putchar(' ');
        }

        n++;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. Цикл `while` можно безболезненно заменить на `for`, будет еще немного короче.

Comment: @eanmos по условию задачи, for использовать нельзя. можно инкремент перенести в условие, но опять же, нет смысла мельчить, лимиты не такие уж жесткие.

Comment: Точно, не прочитал условие.