# Все комбинации из n цифр по возрастанию

Tags: c, алгоритм, комбинаторика

Нужно создать функцию, которая отображает все различные комбинации из n цифр по возрастанию или можно сказать, что каждая правая цифра должна быть больше левой
Условия: 
• n будет находится в диапозоне: **0 < n < 10**

• Если **n = 2**, вот ожидаемый результат:

01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 12 ... 79 89

Если **n = 3**, вот ожидаемый результат:
012 013 014 015 016 017 018 019 023 024 025 026 027 028 029 034 ... 458 459 467 468 469 478 479 489 567 568 569 578 579 589 678 679 689 789

Правила для решения задачи: 
1. Нельзя использовать любой цикл, кроме `while`
2. Нельзя делать динамические массивы, только задавать массив определённой длины, а потом с ним работать
3. Можно использовать только библиотеку `<unistd.h>`
4. Кроме этой функции можно создать ещё три функции, длина каждой функции не должна быть больше 25 строк

Я пробовал решить, но у меня всё время получалась какая-то муть, я не понимаю как задавать, чтобы у меня вложенности проходили несколько раз динамически, либо просто один цикл, с условиями для массива, которые нужно как-то по умному придумать.

Вот пример, как я написал код для 3 цифр, но я просто делал цикл в цикле, возможно можно как-то написать, что n будет передаваться как значения цифр в массиве и их итерировать
:

```
#include <unistd.h>

void    ft_putchar(char letter)
{
    char c;

    c = (char)letter;
    write(1, &c, 1);
}

void    ft_print_comb(void)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;

    i = 0;
    while (i < 10)
    {
        j = i + 1;
        while (j < 10)
        {
            k = j + 1;
            while (k < 10)
            {
                ft_putchar(i + 48);
                ft_putchar(j + 48);
                ft_putchar(k + 48);
                write(1, " ", 1);
                k++;
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}

int     main()
{
    ft_print_comb();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: посмотрите [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1076073/330321)

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Вы действительно думаете, что ТС не смотрел ответ на свой же предыдущий вопрос? :)

Comment: @Эникейщик У него же ясно написано, что n - это длина комбинации, а не разрешенная цифра...

Comment: Да, а зачем вам использовать `write`? Она разве входит в `stdio.h`? А вот `printf` вполне входит...

Comment: @Harry честно говоря, у меня сложилось такое впечатление.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Поставил "птичку" не глядя :) Все же там решалась несколько иная задача...

Comment: @Harry Да, несколько иная, но то решение, как мне кажется, легко адаптируется под эту задачу.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Плохо адаптируется. Чтобы вывести 10 чисел при n=9, нужно перебирать миллиард?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103926/discussion-between---and-harry).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Такое](https://ideone.com/RePzzI) устроит? или где-то не соответствует правилам?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void doit(int n, int t, int b, char * s)
{
    s[t] = '0'+b;
    if (t == n-1)
    {
        printf("%s ",s);
    }
    else
    {
        int i = b + 1;
        while(i <= 9)
        {
            doit(n,t+1,i++,s);
        }
    }
}

void make(int n)
{
    char s[10] = {0};
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 10) doit(n,0,i++,s);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    make(3);
}
```

Comment: нет, вы используете printf(библиотеку stdio.h нельзя использовать), а можно выводить только ascii символ

Comment: Извините, я не заметил, я перепутал, можно использовать только <unistd.h>

Comment: Ну, используйте для вывода свой `write` - как это сделать, надеюсь, вопросов не вызывает? Как получить символ из однозначного числа, знаете? Кстати, не знаю этот unistd, что в нем - но, по-моему, вполне можно заменить printf на `write(1,s,n)` - попробуйте (ну, и дополнительно выводить пробел).

Comment: Я бы с удовольствием использовал printf, но в моей школе нам не разрешается в си использовать такие функции, пока мы их сами не напишем(а напишем тогда, когда прорешаем много задач). У вас в примере для четверки почему-то последнее число вывелось два раза, такого не должно быть

Comment: Harry, поверите вы мне или нет, но я уже пропустил сдачу, и больше не получу балл за эту задачу. Я хочу понять, как она решается.

Comment: вы делали тесты, сравнивали для n = 3? У вас выводится намного больше чисел, чем у меня, у вас при любом n выводится неправильно, кроме n = 10

Comment: Проверяйте исправление.

Comment: Теперь, вроде, всё правильно. Если вам не сложно, могли бы написать комментарии, что происходит в коде русскими словами? Мне это очень сложно понять, хотя я писал код, используя простые рекурсии, а также пользовался указателями

Comment: Смысл вкратце в том, что как, например, построить все тройки? выбрать по очереди в качестве первого символа 0..9 и построить все двойки, начиная со следующего символа. Как построить двойки? вывести нужный символ и построить для него все возможные единицы. doit присваивает t-й символ b, и если он последний - выводит, если нет - вызывает рекурсивно себя же, но уже для t+1 символа, и цифр, больших b.